# How can we refresh events after showing application on Pyside2 for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I want to create a python software with Pyside2 GUI. I've designed the GUI with Qt Designer and I generated a .ui file that I load in my Python script.
I'm looking for a way to put an "event listener" after showing the app to have a modular class, I don't want to put all my connect() methods in the class init.

I can't separate my class initialization and the self.show(), so I need to put these lines after .show() method:

```py
    self.XMLButtonFolder = QPushButton(...)
    self.XMLButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.method)
```

This is my class init (yes it's a thread):

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        loader = QUiLoader()
        print("Loading mainwindow.ui file")
        self.window = loader.load(QFile("mainwindow.ui"))
        if self.window is not None:
            print("mainwindow.ui loaded")
        else:
            print("Error loading mainwindow.ui")


        # XML
        self.XMLButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLButtonFolder")
        self.XMLButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_XML)

        # Report
        self.ReportButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "ReportButtonFolder")
        self.ReportButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_Report)

        # If you uncomment the following line, the eventListener() method will be correctly called ..
        # self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLGenerateReport").clicked.connect(self.eventListener)
        self.window.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())
```

In the same class I added a function to create a new connection and detect "clicked" event from an another button

```py
    def addEventListener(self, qtype, qname):
        self.eventlistenerresult = False
        self.__widget.findChild(self.elementtype[qtype], qname).clicked.connect(self.eventListener)
```

And this is the main program:

```py
myapp = Application()
myapp.addEventListener("Button", "XMLGenerateReport")
```

The problem is I have no method to refresh the window, so the event is not triggered (the one set in the run() method works, but no the one set after)

I want to be able to trigger the event for the button named "XMLGenerateReport", even if the .connect() method is called after .show()

How can we do that ?

Reproductible exemple: (yes I know, in this exemple it can be only have on event, but it's ok for me)
main.py:

```py
from Window import Application
import threading

def GenerateDocument():
    print("Document generated !")

class ProgramThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while not myapp.getEventListenerStatus():
            time.sleep(1.0)
            print("checking Generate button")
        GenerateDocument()


myapp = Application()
myapp.addEventListener("Button", "XMLGenerateReport")
thr = ProgramThread()
thr.start()
```

Window.py:

```py
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QWidget, QLineEdit
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
import sys
import threading


class Application(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    elementtype = {
        "Button": QPushButton
    }

    eventlistenerresult = None

    app = None
    __widget = None

    XMLButtonFolder = None
    ReportButtonFolder = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QApplication([])
        loader = QUiLoader()
        print("Loading mainwindow.ui file")
        self.window = loader.load(QFile("mainwindow.ui"))
        if self.window is not None:
            print("mainwindow.ui loaded")
        else:
            print("Error loading mainwindow.ui")


        # XML
        self.XMLButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLButtonFolder")
        self.XMLButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_XML)

        # Report
        self.ReportButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "ReportButtonFolder")
        self.ReportButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_Report)

        # If you uncomment the following line, the eventListener() method will be correctly called ..
        # self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLGenerateReport").clicked.connect(self.eventListener)
        self.window.show()
        sys.exit(self.app.exec_())

    def openBoxFolder_XML(self):
        # Works
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self.window)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
        path, _ = dialog.getOpenFileName(self.window, 'Sélectionnez un fichier .xml', filter='XML files (*.xml)')
        self.window.findChild(QLineEdit, "XMLInputFolder").setText(path)

    def openBoxFolder_Report(self):
        # Works
        dialog = QFileDialog(self.window)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
        path, _ = dialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.window.findChild(QLineEdit, "ReportInputFolder").setText(path)

    def addEventListener(self, qtype, qname):
        self.eventlistenerresult = False
        self.window.findChild(self.elementtype[qtype], qname).clicked.connect(self.eventListener)

    def eventListener(self):
        # Never called
        print("clicked !")
        self.eventlistenerresult = True

    def getEventListenerStatus(self):
        return self.eventlistenerresult  # Return true if the button handled by addEventListener has been pressed
```

mainwindow.ui:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>696</width>
    <height>222</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="XMLInputFolder">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>531</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="whatsThis">
     <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;Entrez ici le dossier où ce trouve le fichier .xml à utiliser&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="XMLInputFolderLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>40</y>
      <width>171</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Dossier contenant les fichiers .XML</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="XMLGenerateReport">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>150</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Generate</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="ReportInputFolder">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>531</width>
      <height>20</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="ReportInputFolderLabel">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>90</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Dossier de sortie</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="XMLButtonFolder">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>580</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>...</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="ReportButtonFolder">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>580</x>
      <y>110</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>...</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>696</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menuReport_Generation_Level_1">
    <property name="title">
     <string>Fichier</string>
    </property>
    <addaction name="actionQuitter"/>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menuReport_Generation_Level_1"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <action name="actionQuitter">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Quitter</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As Heike points out, you must provide an MRE if you want help, on the other hand you should not run the GUI on another thread since Qt forbids it.

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks for your comment, I added MRE. If I should not run the GUI on an another thread, how can I run my main program while the GUI is loading ?

Thanks !

Comment: 1) Your code is not an MRE, I can not execute your code 2) The heavy task, which I assume is your main program, must be executed in another thread.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the .ui file.
So It's impossible to separate main program (my main.py) from the GUI program ?
I want to make a modular Python program because I want this tool can be modified easily by my teammates.
I think it's more understandable if the program works like this:

main.py -> Window.py
    \
    GenerationScript.py

Instead of

Window.py -> GenerationScript.py

It's my logic (maybe a wrong one)

Comment: Even with the code you have provided is not an MRE since there are only 2 classes that I can not execute (read the link), besides as I already pointed out that you should not run the GUI on another thread.

Comment: @LDami You have to separate the business logic from the GUI, but that does not mean that you must run the GUI in another thread because as I emphasize Qt forbids it. Depending on your business logic should be the interaction between both parties. Your code is not an MRE because as I emphasize if I copy the code you provide, nothing is shown.

Comment: Hm, It's weird it's working on my side (I created 3 files with code I provide to you, executed it with a simple python who have PySide2 installed before with pip, and the GUI is shown). Maybe it missing a "print" to show when the button "Generate" is pressed, even if that does not work :)

By the way I will try to edit my scripts in a different way !

Comment: Showing the GUI does not imply that it works correctly, I have seen cases that seem to work but doing a detailed analysis I found that it only worked by luck. Qt prohibits it from running on another thread because it can not guarantee its operation (that is, it can often work but that does not imply that another part works), reads: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread

Comment: Ok I understood.
I edited my program (I will edit the main topic) with a class for the GUI, called in the main thread, and an another thread who will check the value for the button (If pressed or not). For the moment it still not working ..

Comment: I remember why I've put GUI Window class in a thread: the class init can never be finished. While the program is running, it blocks to "myapp = Application() ; exactly to: self.window.show()", so the method "myapp.addEventListener" can never be executed because the program continue the script only when the window is closed ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that self.app.exec_ () will not allow the following lines to be executed since it allows executing the eventloop, so that line must be executed last. In this case we create a run method that only calls that function:

**Window.py**

```
class Application(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # ...

    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.ReportButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_Report)

        # If you uncomment the following line, the eventListener() method will be correctly called ..
        # self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLGenerateReport").clicked.connect(self.eventListener)
        self.window.show()

    def run(self):
        return self.app.exec_()
```

**main.py**

```
# ...
myapp = Application()
myapp.addEventListener("Button", "XMLGenerateReport")
thr = ProgramThread()
thr.start()
sys.exit(myapp.run())
```

---

Although your previous code can bring long-term problems since eventlistenerresult is a variable that can be accessed in 2 threads which is dangerous since the threads can compete. I prefer to use the signals.

**Window.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools


class Application:
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(arguments)
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        print("Loading mainwindow.ui file")
        self.window = loader.load(QtCore.QFile("mainwindow.ui"))
        if self.window is not None:
            print("mainwindow.ui loaded")
        else:
            print("Error loading mainwindow.ui")
            sys.exit(-1)

        self.XMLButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QPushButton, "XMLButtonFolder"
        )
        self.ReportButtonFolder = self.window.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QPushButton, "ReportButtonFolder"
        )
        self.XMLInputFolder = self.window.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit, "XMLInputFolder"
        )
        self.ReportInputFolder = self.window.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QLineEdit, "ReportInputFolder"
        )
        self.XMLGenerateReport = self.window.findChild(
            QtWidgets.QPushButton, "XMLGenerateReport"
        )

        self.ReportButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_Report)
        self.XMLButtonFolder.clicked.connect(self.openBoxFolder_XML)

        # If you uncomment the following line, the eventListener() method will be correctly called ..
        # self.window.findChild(QPushButton, "XMLGenerateReport").clicked.connect(self.eventListener)
        self.window.show()

    def run(self):
        return self.app.exec_()

    def openBoxFolder_XML(self):
        # Works
        dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog(self.window)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.ExistingFile)
        path, _ = dialog.getOpenFileName(
            self.window,
            "Sélectionnez un fichier .xml",
            filter="XML files (*.xml)",
        )
        self.XMLInputFolder.setText(path)

    def openBoxFolder_Report(self):
        # Works
        dialog = QFileDialog(self.window)
        dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog.Directory)
        path, _ = dialog.getOpenFileName()
        self.ReportInputFolder.setText(path)
```

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PySide2 import QtCore

from Window import Application


def GenerateDocument():
    print("Document generated !")


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def task(self):
        GenerateDocument()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    myapp = Application(sys.argv)

    thread = QtCore.QThread()
    thread.start()

    worker = Worker()
    worker.moveToThread(thread)

    myapp.XMLGenerateReport.clicked.connect(worker.task)

    res = myapp.run()

    thread.quit()
    thread.wait()

    sys.exit(res)
```

Comment: I can't put a +1 because of my reputation, but I want to thank you !
That's work perfectly, Thanks to have taking time to help me !